# Custom scoring function RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Using `RandomSearchCV`, I managed to find a `RandomForestRegressor` with the best hyperparameters. 
But, to this, I used a custom score function matching my specific needs.

Now, I don't know how to use

best_estimator_ - a RandomForestRegressor - returned by the search

**with** my custom scoring function.

Is there a way to pass a custom scoring function to a `RandomForestRegressor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoring function in `RandomizedSearchCV` will only calculate the score of the predicted data from the model for each combination of hyper-parameters specified in the grid, and the hyper-parameters with the highest average score on test folds wins.

It does not in any way alter the behaviour of the internal algorithm of RandomForest (other than finding the hyperparameters, of-course).

Now you have `best_estimator_` (a RandomForestRegressor), with the best found hyper-parameters already set and the model already trained on the whole data you sent to `RandomizedSearchCV` (if you used `refit=True`, which is `True` by default).

So I'm not sure what you want to do with passing that scorer to the model. The `best_estimator_` model can be directly used to get predictions on the new data by using the `predict()` method. After that, the custom scoring you used can be used to compare the predictions with the actual model. There's nothing more to it.

A simple example of this would be:

```
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, make_scorer

X, y = load_boston().data, load_boston().target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

clf = RandomForestRegressor()

# Your custom scoring strategy
def my_custom_score(y_true, y_pred):
    return r2_score(y_true, y_pred)

# Wrapping it in make_scorer to able to use in RandomizedSearch
my_scorer = make_scorer(my_custom_score)

# Hyper Parameters to be tuned
param_dist = {"max_depth": [3, None],
              "max_features": sp_randint(1, 11),
              "min_samples_split": sp_randint(2, 11),}

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(clf, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=20, scoring=my_scorer)
random_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Best found parameters set and model trained on X_train, y_train
best_clf = random_search.best_estimator_

# Get predictions on your new data
y_test_pred = best_clf.predict(X_test)

# Calculate your score on the predictions with respect to actual values
print(my_custom_score(y_test, y_test_pred))
```

Comment: @tehlinger `best_estimator_` is the fitted model.

Comment: Okay, I just had a bad understaning of the difference between hypertuning and fitting. Thank you very much